# Find $y^{(n)}(0)$ for every $n$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Let $y(x)$ fulfill $y''-xy=0$. Furthermore: $y(0)=0,y'(0)=1$. Find $y^{(n)}(0)$ for every $n$. I tried different forms of recurrence relations but I couldn't do much with it without it becoming a complete mess. This is what I got:

$f^{(n+2)}=n\cdot y^{(n-1)}+x\cdot y^{(n)}$.

I would really appreciate your simplifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** write the solution $y$ as a power series $y\colon x\mapsto \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$, and see what the differential equation and the initial conditions impose on the $a_n$'s.

Then, use the relation between $a_n$ and $y^{(n)}(0)$.

Answer (score 2):

Why mess? Because you should calculate $y^{(n)}(0)$, not in other point, it could be not too messy:

$$0=y''-xy, \; \text{so} \; y''(0)=0$$

$$0=(0)'=(y''-xy)'=y^{(3)}-xy'-y \; \text{so} \; y^{(3)}(0)=y(0)=0$$

$$0=(y^{(3)}-xy'-y)'=y^{(4)}-y'-xy'-y^{'}=0  \; \text{so} \;y^{(4)}(0)=2y'(0)=2$$

Can you find a general pattern?

Comment: That is not correct. $y^{(4)}(0)=2..$ because $y''=xy$ and therefore $y^{(3)}=y+xy'$ and $y^{(4)}=y'+y'+xy''$ and therefore $y^{(4)}(0)=2y'(0)+xy''(0)=2+0=2$.

Comment: I'm sorry. It was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

A hint:

Prove, using induction, that
$$y^{(n+3)}=(n+1) y^{(n)}+x y^{(n+1)}\qquad(n\geq0) \ ;$$
then put $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your help. I post this answer as an attempt and application of your advises. Feel free to correct me.

$y=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...+anx^x+...$ 
Since $y(0)=0$, $y=0$ and we get $a_0=0$. Therefore $y=a_1x+a_2x^2+...+anx^x+...$.
$y'(0)=a_1+a_20+....=a_0=1$. Therefore $y=x+a_2x^2+...+anx^n+...$.

$y''=2a_2+2\cdot 3\cdot  a_3+3\cdot4\cdot a_4 x^2+...+(n-1)\cdot n\cdot a_n x^{(n-2)}...=yx=x^2+a_2x^3+...+anx^{n+1}+...$. We get that $a_2=a_3=0,a_n=a_{n+3}\Rightarrow a_4={1\over 3\cdot 4},a_7={1\over 3\cdot 4\cdot6\cdot 7}...a_{3n+1}={1\over 3\cdot4\cdot6\cdot7....(3n-1)\cdot 3n}$ and that $a_2=a_3=a_5=a_6=...=a_{3n}=a_{3n+2}=0$.

Therefore(for $n\ge 2$): $y=x+({1\over 3\cdot 4})\cdot x^ 4+({1\over 3\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 7})\cdot x^7+...+({1\over 3\cdot4\cdot6\cdot7....(3n-1)\cdot 3n})\cdot x^{3n+1}+...$

$y^{(1)}=1+({1\over 3})\cdot x^ 3...$ $\to 1$

$y^{(2)}= x^ 2...$ $\to 0$

$y^{(3)}= 2x...$ $\to 0$

$y^{(4)}= 2...$ $\to 2$

.

.

.

$({1\over 3\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot 7})\cdot 7!...$ $\to 10$
And in 3 more cycles it is again not $0$ but $7!$.

It is easy to see, hence, that:

$y^{(n)}(0) =
\begin{cases}
{n!\over 3\cdot4\cdot6\cdot7....(3k-1)\cdot 3k},  & \text{if $n=3k+1$ with $k\in\Bbb{N}$ } \\[2ex]
0, & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$